# UIViewController force portrait only without code

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, orientation, portrait

I have a view controller which I fire pressing a button from another view controller. This controller shows info about the app and no user interaction is needed on it, hence I didn't create a class for it.

The problem is I need this controller to be in portrait mode only. I know how to force it in code, but since I don't have a class for it, I'm looking for a solution to do it within the storyboard. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: so other viewcontrollers in your app support landscape orientation? i do not think that it is possible then without writing some code... if the whole app only supported portrait orientation you could set that up in your project settings - but i guess you already know that. :)

Comment: So I would have to create a class just for the sake of it? :/

Comment: yeah, i guess so... :) you could just make it work in landscape also. i would recommend that. and you don't need to create a class. keep your head up! :)